# Use of h2o cluster for Neural Network Model

Tags: r, neural-network, artificial-intelligence, cluster-computing, h2o

I'm trying to fit an ANN model to a dataset having 7 predictor variables and the response variable is a binary.

I have converted all the required factor variables to numeric (If I am correct, this is a requirement) and the following error pops up?

**In .h2o.startModelJob(algo, params, h2oRestApiVersion) :
  Dropping bad and constant columns: [Month, Day of Month, Day Of Week].**

Please suggest a way out.

Thanks,
SK

Comment: Are you able to fit any other simple model on your data? Say, a simple ``glm``? If not, then check whether you transform ``factors`` to ``numeric`` correctly. One way is through ``model.matrix()``

Comment: Okay. I'll check if I can do that. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The message about dropping constant columns is not an error.  It is just telling you the model identified that those columns will not impact the predictions and so those columns will be ignored.

Comment: Okay. Thanks for the answer. I have another question, can categorical variables be used in this type of a model?

Comment: Yes, h2o-3 can use categorical columns as inputs for a model.